# Linking.getInitialURL constantly being executed and app being duplicated

Tags: android, react-native

Sorry for the long winded title.

Here's my `componentDidMount()` function

```
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

When I boot up my app, `data` is rightfully set to `null`.

A User then logs in via Google Chrome which is opened via

```
Linking.open('https://...);
```

When the User gets redirected back to my app, I can see that `data` has been populated. This is all well and good.

However, when I am redirected back, I see duplicate components. Here's a screenshot from the React Native Debugger. I have `<AppContainer root=1..>` and `<AppContainer root=11..>`

[image]

Because of this duplication, my app calls `componentDidMount()` twice and `Linking.getInitialURL()` is called multiple times.

Furthermore, if I refresh the app via the developer menu, the `data` returned from `Linking.getInitialURL`'s promise is still populated when it should be `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to my `.MainActivity` activity.

Solution found on [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7079) Github thread.