# Linking.getInitialURL() is not being cleared after used for deeplink

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deeplink

I've had this problem for like 2 weeks. I used [Wix's Navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) for navigating around the app. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/parkerdan/React-Native-Rails-Universal-Linking) for implementing the deeplink/universal link.

I have a base class called `BaseScreen` where I keep all the deeplink handler like in the tutorial. This `BaseScreen` would looks like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    // this handles the case where the app is closed and is launched via Universal Linking.
    Linking.getInitialURL()
        .then((url) => {
          if (url) {
            // Alert.alert('GET INIT URL','initial url  ' + url)
            this.resetStackToProperRoute(url)
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {})

   // This listener handles the case where the app is woken up from the Universal or Deep Linking
   Linking.addEventListener('url', this.appWokeUp);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    // Remove the listener
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.appWokeUp);
  }

  appWokeUp = (event) => {
    // this handles the use case where the app is running in the background and is activated by the listener...
    // Alert.alert('Linking Listener','url  ' + event.url)
    this.resetStackToProperRoute(event.url)
  }

  resetStackToProperRoute = (url) => {
    // grab the trailing portion of the url so we can use that data to fetch proper information from the server
    let trailing = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1, url.length)
    // go to the desired screen with the trailing token grabbed from the url
    this.props.navigator.resetTo({
      screen: 'NewPassword',
      overrideBackPress: true,
      passProps: {
        token: trailing
      },
      animated: true,
      animationType: 'fade',
      navigatorStyle: {
      navBarHidden: true,
  }
})
  }
```

When the app launch, it'll show the screen `LoginScreen` which extends the `BaseScreen` above. After killing the app, click the url from the mail, the app launches `LoginScreen` first, then it'll redirect to the screen `NewPassword`, and after everything has done, I'll redirect back to `LoginScreen` by:

```
this.props.navigator.resetTo({
  screen: 'LoginScreen',
  animated: true,
  overrideBackPress: true,
  animationType: 'fade',
  navigatorStyle: {
    navBarHidden: true,
  }
})
```

But the `Linking.getInitialURL()` of the `LoginScreen` still receive the old url, so it'll redirect to `NewPassword` again, and it's a loop.

I've also tried to pass: `passProps: {}` option when `resetTo` the `LoginScreen` but no luck.

I guess the only way to fix it is to clear the initialUrl manually after everything's done in `NewPassword` screen. The listener for the `BaseScreen` should be there because if I don't kill the app (just minimize it), the listener should be running to navigate to `NewPassword`.

Wix's navigation has a doc for Deeplink, I tried putting method `onNavigatorEvent(event)` into the `BaseScreen` but it doesn't get called. I don't know if I miss something.

Thank you for your time. Any idea would be appreciated

Comment: add android:launchMode="singleTask" to your main .MainActivity in AndroidManifest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752822/linking-getinitialurl-constantly-being-executed-and-app-being-duplicated?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 7):

Linking.getInitialURL() gives us the same Url when we come back to the same page again, to Overcome this we can do a simple condition of not to call the DeepLink function. Something like...

**Step 1:** First init a dummyDeepLinkedUrl String .

```
var dummyDeepLinkedUrl;
```

**Step 2:** Check for the condition like, if deeplinkUrl is coming from Linking.getInitialURL() and deeplinkUrl is not equal to the dummyDeepLinkedUrl .

```
if (url && url != dummyDeepLinkedUrl) {}
```

**Step 3:** If not same call the Deeplink Function and assign the deeplinkUrl to dummyDeepLinkedUrl.

```
    this.navigateToRespectivePage(url);
    dummyDeepLinkedUrl = url;
```

Finally this will look like :

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
      if (url && url != dummyDeepLinkedUrl) {
        this.navigateToRespectivePage(url);
        dummyDeepLinkedUrl = url;
      }
    });
```

Comment: If I need to come back with the same URL, and need to do redirection then will it work?

Comment: This will not clear the link and allow for a second launch with the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

> There are two ways to handle URLs that open your app.
>
> 1. If the app is already open, the app is foregrounded and a Linking event is fired You can handle these events with
>      Linking.addEventListener(url, callback).
> 2. If the app is not already open, it is opened and the url is passed in as the initialURL You can handle these events with
>      Linking.getInitialURL(url) -- it returns a Promise that resolves to
>      the url, if there is one.

You can read [more detail](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#handling-deep-links)
Here is the example

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      initialised: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
    Linking.addEventListener('url', event => {
       console.log('deep link from background', event.url)
    })
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = async (nextAppState) => {
    const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
    if (url !== null && !this.state.initialised) {
      this.setState({ initialised: true })
      console.log('deep link from init app', url)
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
    Linking.removeEventListener('url')
  }
}
```